# Looking for a hint (not the answer) on how to return the longest acsending non contiguous substring when I already have the length

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

My code currently returns the length of the largest substring:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=l-1;i++)
{
   counter = 1;

   for(int j = 0; j<i;j++)
   {
      if(seq[j]<seq[j+1])
      {
         count[j] = counter++;    
      }
   }
}
     for(int i = 0;i<l-1;i++)
     {
        if(largest < count[i+1])
        {
           largest = count[i+1];
        }

     }
```

assuming seq is the numbers in the sequence. So if the sequence is: 5;3;4;8;6;7, it prints out 4. However, I would like it to also print out 3;4;6;7 which is the longest subsisting in ascending order.

***I am trying to get the length of the largest sub sequence itself and the actual sequence, but I already have length..***
My instinct is to store each number in the array, while it is working out the count, with the count. So returning the longest count, can also return the array attatched to it. I think this can be done with hashtables, but I'm not sure how to use those.

I am just looking for a hint, not the answer.

Thanks

Comment: I originally upvoted - but I'm confused. Why does it print out 4? I think you need to show us more code.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, you should try to elaborate exactly what you want

Comment: I added the part where it acquires the length of the largest sub sequence.

Comment: I made it more clear as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a dynamic programming algorithm for the [*longest ascending subsequence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence). The idea is to store a pair of values for each position `i`:

- The length of the longest ascending subsequence that ends at position `i`
- The index of the item preceding the current one in such ascending subsequence, or `-1` if all prior numbers are greater than or equal to the current one.

You can easily build both these arrays by setting the first pair to `{Length=1, Prior=-1}`, walking the array in ascending order, and looking for the "best" predecessor for the current item at index `i`. The predecessor must fit these two conditions:

- It must have lower index and be smaller than the item at `i`, and
- It must end an ascending subsequence of length greater than the one that you have found so far.

Here is how the data would look for your sequence:

```
Index:        0  1  2  3  4  5
Value:        5  3  4  8  6  7
------------  ----------------
Length:       1  1  2  3  3  4
Predecessor: -1 -1  1  2  2  4
```

Once you finish the run, find the max value among `length`s array, and chain it back to the beginning using the predecessor's indexes until you hit `-1`.

Comment: I am under standing everything but use of the predecessor part, what does this tell you? Thanks.

Comment: @user2396852 The predecessor lets you reconstruct the subsequence itself, not just getting its length. Once you find that the best length is 4, you print value `7`, then go to its predecessor at index 4, print `6`, then go to its predecessor at index 2, print `4`, go to its predecessor at index 1, print `3`, see that its predecessor is `-1`, and stop. You have now printed `7, 6, 4, 3` - the sequence that you are seeking in reverse order.

Comment: @user2396852 Technically, you don't need the predecessor: you can reconstruct the sequence going by length: start with 4, then go back looking for 3 (and check the value to be less than the value with length 4), then for 2, and finally for 1. It trades speed for memory, because you can drop one array, but in exchange you must re-check the condition that you have already checked once.

Comment: Wow, that's a really clever concept, but couldn't you just do the same things with the lengths. Start at length `4` which is `7`, then go to length `3` at `6`, length `2` at `4` and then length `1` at 3. thus printing out: 7,6,4,3. Wouldn't this make the need for the predecessor array obsolete?

I see you just answered my question before I sent it. Thanks anyway :)