# The best way to get the index of a number in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

My program finds the length sub-string in that goes in ascending order that does not have to be contiguous.

So if I were to enter: `5;3;4;8;6;7`

The output would be: `4`

I would like my program to output the largest sub-sequence as well. And to do this, I would need the index of certain parts of the array: `5;3;4;8;6;7`, as illustrated in a question I previously asked: [Looking for a hint (not the answer) on how to return the longest acsending non contiguous substring when I already have the length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886038/looking-for-a-hint-not-the-answer-on-how-to-return-the-longest-acsending-non-c)

So if the input was: `5;3;4;8;6;7`

```
Index:        0  1  2  3  4  5
Value:        5  3  4  8  6  7
------------  ----------------
Length:       1  1  2  3  3  4
Predecessor: -1 -1  1  2  2  4
```

I would need the index of each time the Length value, is one smaller than the previous value.So I would need the index of: `6,,8,4,3 and 5` However I am not sure how to get the indexes of these values in Java. Is there a method that would allow me to do this easily?

Comment: How do you calculate Predecessor here? Just asking to know.

Comment: I created a for loop, to get the index of where the Length is the largest. So you will always have the first number. However I am not sure what to do when you have multiple lengths of the same value.
         `for(int i = 0;i<l-1;i++)
         {
            if(largest < count[i+1])
            {
               largest = count[i+1];
             
            }
            indexLargest++;
         }`

Comment: if you are doing several calculations with the same array you might want to iterate through the array once and store the index and value in a hashmap. Key is number. value is index. Then you can just go index (aka 5) =  map.get(7)

Answer (score 0):

While not an array, I'ld use a List and [indexOf(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)